# Возможен ли перевод даты типа 930 или 1030 в unix формат в php?

Tags: php, дата, время

Я новичок в php. Сейчас делаю один скрипт, работающий с временем. У меня есть массив времени, который я релизовал как 930,1030,1230 и.т.д. С этим массивом просиходят различные действия с использованием функций и по итогу мне нужно вернуть время в формате unix. По моей задумке это выглядит так - берём начало сегодня в unix функцией mktime, а затем прибавляем 930,1030,1230 и.т.д. Но я забыл учесть что такие числа нельзя просто напросто даже умножить на часы (3600) что будет неккоректно. Возникает вопрос - можно ли вообще функциями php перевести дату типа 930 в unixtime?

Answer (score 2):

[SUBSTR](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
если я правильно понимаю, то 930 - это 9:30
Тогда проще всего

```
$minutes = intVal(substr($wierdTime,-2));
$hours = intVal(substr($wierdTime,0,-2));
```

N.B. Не надо так дату писать.

Comment: ого! просто я не мог в ассоциативный массив почему-то занести формат с : теперь поинмаю что это было зря...спасибо!! попробую ваш метод!

Answer (score 1):

Можно [дополнить](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php) ведущий нуль к часам и воспользоваться методом [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$time = '930';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Hi', str_pad($time, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
echo $dt->getTimestamp(), PHP_EOL; // 1530171000 - unix timestamp
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // 2018-06-28 09:30 - тут будет текущий день
```

---

Если нужно только количество секунд с **текущей полуночи**(разве это unixtime?), его можно посчитать:

```
echo ($dt->format('H')*60 + $dt->format('i'))*60; //34200
```